# Checking web/mobile access when shouldOverrideUrlLoading fires

Tags: android, url, webview, overriding

Is there a way I can put an if statement inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading() which checks for web/mobile access.  Then display an error message instead of the nasty page not found page that mobile chrome displays.

Something similar to

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
 {        
    if(isOnline() == false)  
        {
         AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         dlgAlert.setMessage("Mobile device currnetly has no internet access.  Please try again.");
         dlgAlert.setTitle("No Connection");
         dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
         dlgAlert.setCancelable(true); 
         dlgAlert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
         dlgAlert.create().show(); 
        }

        return false;          
 }
```

Comment: that should work - assuming you have a method called isOnline that checks the network status. just return true in the if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution for my problem.  First of all I put the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() in new WevViewclient.  Before I had it outside of that block.

Next I was getting an error message for

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Next I changed the code to this, using Toast messages instead of  AlertDialog Builder.

@Override
             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
             {

```
             if (isOnline() == false)
             {
                 Toast msg = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No mobile or web access, try again later.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                 msg.show();
                 return true;
             }
             else
             { 
                 return false;
            }
         }
```